# (JQuery) Select input when I use TAB

Tags: jquery, forms, select, input, tabs

I would like to select input in a form when I focus in.
I tried to write this :

```
    $(".myForm").on("focusin", "input", function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
```

The select works fine when I click on the input, it's select all the text, but it doesn't work when I use the TAB key :(
Is there a way to be sure that the text into the input will be selected when I focus on it with the TAB key ? I tried a solution with a select() inside a settimeout but it seems very ugly.

**edit:**

I got it! To avoid users from putting anything else than numbers in my input, I had that code, which created the problem:

```
$(".myForm").on("keyup", "input", function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9 .]/g, '');
  });
```

So I changed it to the following:

```
  $(".myForm").on("keyup", "input", function () {
        var matches = this.value.match(/[^0-9 .]/g);
        if (matches != null) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9 .]/g, '');
        }
  });
```

Now it works fine :)

Comment: I had to try 15 time before it was ok to submit this question. The thing worked when I add the "I would like to " at the beggining... Stackoverflow, your algorythm seems powerfull but a little bit stubborn ^^

Comment: What browser and version are you using?  This seems to work for me in [Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/4gzynt7x/).

Comment: I also use Chrome, and the last version.

Comment: And I don't really understand why I have a minus and the Thierry Lathuille rejected vote, is my question not clear or something ? What a welcoming :/

Comment: It works fine on firefox :/

Comment: You should check to see if you have other javascript errors on your page.  Try to run only this.  *Remember to run on page load!*  If this gets run before the page has loaded your form, jQuery will search for .myForm, find nothing, and run normally but not assign the event listener.

Comment: Yep, all the code is on a $(document).ready function. The thing which is funny is that it actually select the content of the input, but one millisecond after, it deselect it and the cursor comes at the end of the input text. And as I said, I don't have this problem on firefox, so I really don't see where it could come from.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.  :)